# How to make custom field in DRF Serializer?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have model Transasction

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

and other models that have OneToOneField with Transasction.

```
class RefillTransactionData(models.Model):
    transaction = models.OneToOneField(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PurchaseTransactionData(models.Model):
    transaction = models.OneToOneField(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I create a Serializer with a custom field "data" which will contain other serializers?

A Json shema should be like this

```
{
    created_at: "2020-10-01"
    data: {
        RefillTransactionData: {},
        PurchaseTransactionData: {}
    }
}
```

For GET request I can do this with the `to_representation` method, but I need the same things for all request types.

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.fields import Field, SerializerMethodField

class DictField(Field):
    """
    A field handle dict fields
    """
    type_name = 'dictfield'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.style = {'base_template': 'textarea.html'}

    def to_representation(self, value):
        """" custom"""
        # do the customization according to u
        if isinstance(value, dict) or value is None:
            return value

    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        """ """
        # you can check and validate the data fromat
        if value == '' or value is None:
            return value
        pass

    def validate_empty_values(self, data):
        if data == '':
            self.fail('required')
        return super().validate_empty_values(data)
```